# Sublime Text 3 displaying .gitignore as binary

Tags: git, sublimetext, gitignore

Has anyone encountered this issue where Sublime Text 3 displays your .gitignore as a binary file? If so, can you help me understand how/why this is happening, and how to fix this issue? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Can you check the mime-type of this file? Assuming you're on linux `file --mime .gitignore`

Comment: Interesting: `.gitignore: application/octet-stream; charset=binary`

Comment: Thanks @crea1,  I was able to open the file with text edit. So, I simply deleted the .gitignore file in the project and replace it's contents by copying and pasting from text edit. I'm still wondering how/why the file was converted to binary. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: That's great! I'm guessing you had a special character hidden in there somewhere. I found this: http://superuser.com/a/411391

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: filetype should be text/plain
.gitignore: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

In order to find how it got introduced,  you can use git log (assuming the .gitignore was working at some point)